# Linking error when building OpenJDK8 with gcc 6

Tags: c++, gcc, java

I am trying to build OpenJDK 8 with gcc6:

```
$ hg clone http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8 jdk8
$ cd jdk8
$ bash get_source.sh
$ bash ./configure
$ make images
```

As explained [here](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8151841) or [here](https://patchwork.openembedded.org/patch/139474/), I had to update make files to add the following options to gcc:

```
-Wno-deprecated-declarations 
-Wno-error=deprecated-declarations 
-Wno-error=narrowing 
-fno-exceptions 
-fvisibility=hidden 
-fno-delete-null-pointer-checks 
-fno-lifetime-dse
```

It seems that everything compiles fine now. 
However, when linking it fails on the following command:

```
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-6
-Xlinker --hash-style=both
-Xlinker -z
-Xlinker defs -shared
-L/home/johnd/src/build_jdk/jdk8/jdk/lib/amd64
-L/home/johnd/src/build_jdk/jdk8/jdk/lib/amd64/server
-Xlinker -z
-Xlinker origin
-Xlinker -rpath
-Xlinker \$ORIGIN
-Xlinker -version-script=/home/johnd/src/build_jdk/jdk8/jdk/make/mapfiles/libzip/mapfile-vers
-Xlinker -soname=libzip.so
-o /home/johnd/src/build_jdk/jdk8/jdk/lib/amd64/libzip.so
/home/johnd/src/build_jdk/jdk8/jdk/objs/libzip/Adler32.o
/home/johnd/src/build_jdk/jdk8/jdk/objs/libzip/CRC32.o
/home/johnd/src/build_jdk/jdk8/jdk/objs/libzip/Deflater.o
/home/johnd/src/build_jdk/jdk8/jdk/objs/libzip/Inflater.o
/home/johnd/src/build_jdk/jdk8/jdk/objs/libzip/ZipFile.o
/home/johnd/src/build_jdk/jdk8/jdk/objs/libzip/compress.o
/home/johnd/src/build_jdk/jdk8/jdk/objs/libzip/deflate.o
/home/johnd/src/build_jdk/jdk8/jdk/objs/libzip/gzclose.o
/home/johnd/src/build_jdk/jdk8/jdk/objs/libzip/gzlib.o
/home/johnd/src/build_jdk/jdk8/jdk/objs/libzip/gzread.o
/home/johnd/src/build_jdk/jdk8/jdk/objs/libzip/gzwrite.o
/home/johnd/src/build_jdk/jdk8/jdk/objs/libzip/infback.o
/home/johnd/src/build_jdk/jdk8/jdk/objs/libzip/inffast.o
/home/johnd/src/build_jdk/jdk8/jdk/objs/libzip/inflate.o
/home/johnd/src/build_jdk/jdk8/jdk/objs/libzip/inftrees.o
/home/johnd/src/build_jdk/jdk8/jdk/objs/libzip/trees.o
/home/johnd/src/build_jdk/jdk8/jdk/objs/libzip/uncompr.o
/home/johnd/src/build_jdk/jdk8/jdk/objs/libzip/zadler32.o
/home/johnd/src/build_jdk/jdk8/jdk/objs/libzip/zcrc32.o
/home/johnd/src/build_jdk/jdk8/jdk/objs/libzip/zip_util.o
/home/johnd/src/build_jdk/jdk8/jdk/objs/libzip/zutil.o
-ljvm
-ljava
```

It gives the following error:

```
/home/johnd/src/build_jdk/jdk8/jdk/objs/libzip/ZipFile.o: In function `Java_java_util_zip_ZipFile_open':
/home/johnd/src/build_jdk/jdk8/jdk/src/share/native/java/util/zip/ZipFile.c:109: undefined reference to `throwFileNotFoundException'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This is surprising since symbol `throwFileNotFoundException' is apparently defined in libjava which is given as parameter to the linker.

```
$ nm ./jdk/lib/amd64/libjava.so | grep throw
000000000001b0cd t throwFileNotFoundException
000000000001721b t throwIOException
```

Any idea what is going on and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the latest version of OpenJDK8 has still not been patched for gcc6. Here is how I did to use the patches from Debian's OpenJDK8 package to patch OpenJDK8 for gcc6:

```
# apt-get install build-essentials
# apt-get build-dep openjdk-8
$ apt-get source openjdk-8
```

Here is the list of the patches in the Debian package:

```
$ ls -1 openjdk-8-8u144-b01/debian/patches/
8141491.diff
8164293.diff
aarch32.diff
aarch64.diff
accessible-toolkit.patch
adlc-parser.patch
alpha-float-const.diff
applet-hole.patch
atk-wrapper-security.patch
autoconf-select.diff
autoconf-updates.diff
bootstrap-with-gcj.diff
compare-pointer-with-literal.patch
compiler-flags.diff
default-jvm-cfg-aarch64.diff
default-jvm-cfg-default.diff
disable-doclint-by-default.diff
dnd-files.patch
dont-strip-images.diff
enumipv6-fix.patch
fontconfig-japanese.diff
fontconfig-korean-nanum.diff
fontconfig-wqy-microhei.patch
gcc6.diff
[...]
```

Before applying the patches, download the latest OpenJDK8 source:

```
$ hg clone http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u
$ cd jdk8u
$ bash get_source.sh
```

Then apply the patches:

```
$ patch -p1 < /path/to/openjdk-8-8u144-b01/debian/patches/gcc6.diff
$ patch -p1 < /path/to/openjdk-8-8u144-b01/debian/patches/8141491.diff
$ patch -p1 < /path/to/openjdk-8-8u144-b01/debian/patches/hotspot-warn-no-errformat.diff
$ patch -p1 < /path/to/openjdk-8-8u144-b01/debian/patches/hotspot-set-compiler.diff
$ patch -p1 < /path/to/openjdk-8-8u144-b01/debian/patches/hotspot-disable-werror.diff
```

Then compile:

```
$ bash ./configure
$ make
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have cloned the JDK 8 GA sources (i.e. 2014). They predate gcc6 by about two years.

Instead, please clone the latest source code from JDK 8 Updates Project, and try again, i.e.using hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u .

Comment: Thanks for you reply! I have tried using http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u. Unfortunately, it still fails with gcc6. I used patches from Debian's package to make it work as explained in the answer below.